DevTools Failed to load response data. No data found for resource with given identifier
I have an angular application with a .NET Core server. From the devtools on the network screen I am trying to see the response that has a request. This request works fine, it returns data (well formed), and the application works based on that data, but in the Preview screen no data appears (nor in Response).

The same request in postman:

It happens randomly with some requests, while others do return data.

Why does this happen and how do I fix it? I'm using the latest version of Microsoft Edge, but it also happens in other browsers such as Chrome. Thanks in advance

If you're requesting JSON data, it might be too large which cause this issue. You can refer to this similar thread: failed to load response data request content was evicted from inspector cache.
If the application works well, I suggest that you can ignore the issue in chromium devtools and still use postman as a workaround.

It is not too large, it has data but it is something normal. But it seems not to be the problem because if i edit and resend the request in DevTools in that case the response JSON shows fine, and is the same request with same data returned. I can use postman or edit and resend the request but for debug purposes is more comfortable just to see it in the preview console at the first time

Could you please provide the steps to reproduce the issue so that we can have a test?
